# Mysql: Query to Join Table Data Based On Closest Timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have Table in Mysql and I need to be able join the data based on the nearest timestamp in with the matching row [that may be earlier than or equal to or greater than the timestamp[but nearest] of another row based on username].

Here is Sample data Mysql Table:

```
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+
| Id | userName | Browser | Platform | TS                  |
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | abc      | Firefox | NULL     | 2006-10-05 11:55:45 |
|  2 | xyz      | Chrome  | NULL     | 2007-10-07 12:34:17 |
|  3 | mnp      | Safari  | NULL     | 2008-10-09 08:19:37 |
|  4 | abc      | Safari  | NULL     | 2010-10-13 04:28:14 |
|  5 | abc      | NULL    | Windows  | 2006-01-01 12:02:45 |
|  6 | xyz      | NULL    | Linux    | 2007-01-01 12:01:20 |
|  7 | mnp      | NULL    | MAC      | 2008-01-01 12:02:29 |
|  8 | abc      | NULL    | MAC      | 2010-03-09 13:06:59 |
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

And I need output like Following:

```
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+
| Id | userName | Browser | Platform | TS                  |
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | abc      | Firefox | Windows  | 2006-10-05 11:55:45 |
|  2 | xyz      | Chrome  | Linux    | 2007-10-07 12:34:17 |
|  3 | mnp      | Safari  | MAC      | 2008-10-09 08:19:37 |
|  4 | abc      | Safari  | MAC      | 2010-10-13 04:28:14 |
|  5 | abc      | Firefox | Windows  | 2006-01-01 12:02:45 |  
|  6 | xyz      | Chrome  | Linux    | 2007-01-01 12:01:20 |
|  7 | mnp      | Safari  | MAC      | 2008-01-01 12:02:29 |
|  8 | abc      | Safari  | MAC      | 2010-03-09 13:06:59 |
+----+----------+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

Can Anyone suggest a mysql query needed to get desired output

Comment: "earlier than or equal to or greater than" this makes no logical sense whatsoever

Comment: Here the intention is to map the entries/data collected at a different span. This helps us to find out which browser and PC that he is using at that moment. Of course may not be, But we want to manage in this way.

Comment: are you using MySQL 8.x?  Need to know the version of MySQL to choose relevant solution options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And in case you are in an earlier version of mysql, which doesn't support analytical functions:

(This should be equivalent to the other answer by @Used_By_Already)

```
SELECT 
  t2.Id, 
  t2.userName, 
  COALESCE(t2.Browser, t2.other_Browser), 
  COALESCE(t2.Platform, t2.other_Platform),
  t2.TS, 
  t2.other_TS
from (

SELECT 
  t.*,
  IF (t.Id = @prev_id, @rankk:=@rankk+1, @rankk:=0) as rankk,
  @prev_id := t.Id
from (
  select 
    a.Id, a.userName, a.Browser , a.Platform, a.TS, 
    b.Id as other_Id, b.Browser as other_Browser , b.Platform as other_Platform, b.TS as other_TS,
    ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.TS, b.TS)) as time_diff
  from mytable a join mytable b on a.userName = b.userName and a.Id <> b.Id
  order by a.Id, ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.TS, b.TS)))
  t join (select @prev_Id:=NULL, @rankk:=0) c
) t2
 WHERE rankk=0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have MySQL v8, or MariaDb, that supports `lead() over()`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(
>    Id       INT
>   ,userName VARCHAR(10)
>   ,Browser  VARCHAR(9)
>   ,Platform VARCHAR(10)
>   ,TS       timestamp
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable(Id,userName,Browser,Platform,TS) VALUES >     >     >     >     >       (1,'abc','Firefox',NULL,'2006-10-05 11:55:45');
> , (2,'xyz','Chrome',NULL,'2007-10-07 12:34:17');
> , (3,'mnp','Safari',NULL,'2008-10-09 08:19:37');
> , (4,'abc','Safari',NULL,'2010-10-13 04:28:14')
> , (5,'abc',NULL,'Windows','2006-01-01 12:02:45')
> , (6,'xyz',NULL,'Linux','2007-01-01 12:01:20')
> , (7,'mnp',NULL,'MAC','2008-01-01 12:02:29')
> , (8,'abc',NULL,'MAC','2010-03-09 13:06:59')
> ```

> ```
> with cte as (
> select
> *
> , coalesce(lead(ts) over(order by ts),current_time) nxt
> from mytable
> )
> select
>   id
> , username
> , coalesce(browser,(select browser from cte where t.ts between cte.ts and cte.nxt limit 1 )) browser
> , coalesce(platform,(select platform from cte where t.ts between cte.ts and cte.nxt limit 1 )) platform
> , ts
> , nxt
> from cte t
> ```
>
> ```
> id | username | browser | platform | ts                  | nxt                
> -: | :------- | :------ | :------- | :------------------ | :------------------
>  5 | abc      | null    | Windows  | 2006-01-01 12:02:45 | 2006-10-05 11:55:45
>  1 | abc      | Firefox | Windows  | 2006-10-05 11:55:45 | 2007-01-01 12:01:20
>  6 | xyz      | Firefox | Linux    | 2007-01-01 12:01:20 | 2007-10-07 12:34:17
>  2 | xyz      | Chrome  | Linux    | 2007-10-07 12:34:17 | 2008-01-01 12:02:29
>  7 | mnp      | Chrome  | MAC      | 2008-01-01 12:02:29 | 2008-10-09 08:19:37
>  3 | mnp      | Safari  | MAC      | 2008-10-09 08:19:37 | 2010-03-09 13:06:59
>  8 | abc      | Safari  | MAC      | 2010-03-09 13:06:59 | 2010-10-13 04:28:14
>  4 | abc      | Safari  | MAC      | 2010-10-13 04:28:14 | 2018-10-02 08:11:44
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d519ece812c3b32363906de085c88e1b)*

Comment: Thanks, mysql that i am using is 5.7.23.