# SQL Statement to get all entries in timerange based on identifier

Tags: database, mariadb

I'm storing interface data from my Router gathered through SNMP in a MariaDB. The data is structured in the following way (simplified):

```
id     TIMESTAMP              READING              VALUE
============================================================
100    2020-04-15 11:29:51    if03_name            eth0
101    2020-04-15 11:29:51    if03_totalBytesRx    654321
102    2020-04-15 11:29:51    if03_totalBytesTx    123456
103    2020-04-15 11:30:51    if03_totalBytesRx    765432
104    2020-04-15 11:30:51    if03_totalBytesTx    234567
```

Now to get the data received and transmitted for `eth0` it is easily possible to select on the `READING` `if03_totalBytesRx` or `if03_totalBytesTx`.

For instance, I can execute the following query to get the average bits per second received at any given time:

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMP,
    GREATEST(0,(VALUE - LAG(VALUE,1) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP))*8/(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAG(TIMESTAMP,1) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP)))) as value
FROM history
WHERE
    READING = "if03_totalBytesRx"
```

Unfortunately, sometimes (I believe when an interface goes down and up again) the mapping between `READING` and interface changes, such that `if03` is not `eth0` any more (`if03` could for instance be `eth1` or also `noSuchInstance`), whereas `eth0` is assigned another `READING`, for example `if29`:

```
id     TIMESTAMP              READING              VALUE
============================================================
200    2020-04-15 12:16:51    if03_totalBytesRx    876543
201    2020-04-15 12:16:51    if03_totalBytesTx    345678
202    2020-04-15 12:17:51    if03_name            noSuchInstance
203    2020-04-15 12:17:51    if03_totalBytesRx    noSuchInstance
204    2020-04-15 12:17:51    if03_totalBytesTx    noSuchInstance
205    2020-04-15 12:17:51    if29_name            eth0
206    2020-04-15 12:17:51    if29_totalBytesRx    987654
207    2020-04-15 12:17:51    if29_totalBytesTx    456789
```

Note that `if03_name` is only stored in the DB when changed, not every minute.

Obviously that causes either no data when querying the `READING` `if03_totalBytesRx` (in the case of `noSuchInstance`) or false data, i.e. data from another interface.

What would be a viable way to select all the `ifXX_totalBytesRx` and `ifXX_totalBytesTx` for all the timeranges where the corresponding `ifXX_name` equals to `eth0`? (E.g. in the example above the union of 11:29:51 to 12:17:50 using `if03` plus everything from 12:17:51 to `NOW()` using `if29`, assuming that id 207 is the last entry in the database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found a solution myself, however it is kind of slow, so I'm happy about any improvements:

First, I created a view `ubnt` that splits the original `READING` into a new field `INTERFACE` (the part before the underscore) and another field `READING` (the part after the underscore, reusing the name):

```
SELECT
    id,
    TIMESTAMP,
    substring_index(READING,'_',1) AS INTERFACE,
    substring_index(READING,'_',-1) AS READING,
    VALUE
FROM history
WHERE READING like 'if%'
```

The second step is to create another view from this called `ubnt_if` that shows the timerange of a logical to physical interface mapping:

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMP AS START,
    COALESCE(LEAD(TIMESTAMP,1) OVER ( PARTITION BY INTERFACE ORDER BY TIMESTAMP),NOW()) AS END,
    INTERFACE AS LOGICAL,
    VALUE AS PHYSICAL
FROM ubnt
WHERE READING = 'name'
```

The third step is to join the interface to the original data, based on the timestamp. For this, I used another view called `ubnt_int`:

```
SELECT
    a.TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP,
    a.READING AS READING,
    a.VALUE AS VALUE,
    b.PHYSICAL AS INTERFACE
FROM (
    ubnt a
    LEFT JOIN ubnt_if b ON(
        a.INTERFACE = b.LOGICAL AND
        a.TIMESTAMP BETWEEN b.START AND b.END
    )
)
```

This generates a table of data that I can filter based on the physical interface, not the "logical" interface that could change.

I was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580505/mysql-query-to-join-table-data-based-on-closest-timestamp#52603574) to another question.